# Войти удалено в режим суперпользователя на Debian 10 с помощью python paramiko

Tags: python, root, sudo, paramiko

Нужно с помощью языка Python удаленно по ssh поменять на ОС Debian 10 ip-адрес с помощью библиотеки paramiko.
Чтобы изменить ip-адрес, нужно войти в режим суперпользователя через `su`.

Делаю это через через

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')
stdin.write("root" + "\n")
stdin.flush()
```

но код на этом просто виснет и ничего не происходит.

Как решить данную проблему или, возможно, есть другой способ войти в режим суперпользователя?

Вот мой код:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("192.168.1.1", username="user", password="root", port=22)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uptime")
stdin.flush()
result = stdout.read().splitlines()
print(result)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')
stdin.write("root" + "\n")
stdin.flush()

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo ifconfig ens33 192.168.1.15 netmask 255.255.255.0")
stdin.flush()
result = stdout.read().splitlines()
print(result)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ip a")
stdin.flush()
result = stdout.read().splitlines()
print(result)
ssh.close()
```

Comment: возможно, у вас удаленная машине не успевает обработать команду su, когда вы уже пароль отсылаете. перед отправкой пароля сделайте паузу

Comment: Добавил после
`stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')`

`time.sleep(100)`

но все равно не помогло

Comment: А зачем вам su если далее идет ifconfig с sudo. оно и так повысит привилегии. главное что бы в sudoers для текущего пользователя было разрешено выполнять ifconfig. sudo для того и нужно, что бы выполнять команды под рутом не вводя его пароль